# Python - Function has a list as argument. How to return another list without changing the first?

Tags: python, return-value, function-declaration

I'm pretty new in Python (and programming as a whole). I'm pretty sure the answer to this is obvious, but I really don't know what to do.

```
def do_play(value, slot, board):
    temp=board
    (i,j) = slot
    temp[i][j] = value
    return temp
```

board is a list of lists. value is an integer. slot is and integer tuple.

What I am trying to do here is to

- feed the function board
- copy board to a new list called temp
- insert a new value in a specific location in temp
- return temp, leaving board unchanged

When I run this is the shell, both the the original list (board) and the new list (temp) change.
= \

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to see the rest of the program.

Comment: Welcome to Python. Quick note: the parentheses around `i, j` in `(i, j) = slot` aren't necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`temp=board` does not make a new board. It makes the `temp` variable reference the very same list as `board`. So changing `temp[i][j]` changes `board[i][j]` too.

To make a copy, use

```
import copy
temp=copy.deepcopy(board)
```

---

Note that `temp=board[:]` makes `temp` refer to a new list (different than `board`, but the contents (that is, the lists within the list) are still the same:

```
In [158]: board=[[1,2],[3,4]]    
In [159]: temp=board[:]
```

Modifying `temp` modifies `board` too:

```
In [161]: temp[1][0]=100    
In [162]: temp
Out[162]: [[1, 2], [100, 4]]    
In [163]: board
Out[163]: [[1, 2], [100, 4]]
```

`id` shows the object's memory address. This shows `temp` and `board` are different lists:

```
In [172]: id(temp)
Out[172]: 176446508

In [173]: id(board)
Out[173]: 178068780   # The ids don't match
```

But this shows the second list inside `temp` is the very same list inside `board`:

```
In [174]: id(temp[1])
Out[174]: 178827948

In [175]: id(board[1])
Out[175]: 178827948    # The ids are the same
```

---

But if you use `copy.deepcopy`, then the lists within the list also get copied, which is what you need if modifying `temp` is to leave `board` unchanged:

```
In [164]: import copy    
In [165]: board=[[1,2],[3,4]]    
In [166]: temp=copy.deepcopy(board)    
In [167]: temp[1][0]=100    
In [168]: temp
Out[168]: [[1, 2], [100, 4]]    
In [169]: board
Out[169]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to copy `board`?

```
temp = board[:]
```

Or maybe this to copy the structure.

```
temp = [ r[:] for r in board ]
```

Comment: This will only copy the top level. It appears that `board` is a list of lists based on the indexing performed on `temp` a few lines further down.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to copy the object.

Answer (score 2):

Here `temp` is a reference to `board`, a shallow copy. I usually like to import the copy module (`import copy`) and use `copy.deepcopy` which makes `temp` separate from board. You'd call it something like this:

```
import copy
temp = copy.deepcopy(board)
```

Otherwise, you can just make a slice of board (which also makes a deep copy). I believe this should work, but I haven't tried it on a list of lists. You'd call it as so:

```
temp = board[:]
```

Comment: `[:]` operator does not make a deep copy. you had it right with your first option.

Comment: Thanks! I was very much guessing with the slicing.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp=board
```

This doesn't copy list, it just makes one more [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type) to the same object. Use `temp = board[:]` instead.